# Stop default launch of IE from an NFC "tap and send"

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, nfc

We have a very simple demo app with the Windows Phone map app sending a link via 'tap and send' to an NFC tablet. I can get and read the URL coming over, but Windows 8 pops over a purple bar in the top right asking if I want to receive content from another device, which then opens IE to the URL.

Is there an easy way to stop the default Windows behavior (not have the purple bar slide in)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of disabling the toast pop-up and still have the OS launch the browser by default.

When not inside of a "metro style" app toast will always should for incoming proximity payloads such as an NFC tap, however if you are inside of your application you can subscribe to the proximity events and respond with your own user experiences, which means you don't have to show the toast. However when you are in the OS/Start Menu experience Windows always mandates the toast I'm afraid.

In addition; following on from the title of your question NFC tags respond based on the default program for the MIME type/extension on the tag (if using a URL). So if you want a custom experience instead of IE launching you can register your app again an extension or protocol such as map://mydataUrl and Windows will automatically launch your app when you acknowledge the toast popup.

Comment: thanks! Can you clarify in the 2nd paragraph? I am running the Proximity C# Sample application and have subscribed to tap and send messages. I'm getting the message but the toast is still showing up. How specifically do I turn the toast off?

Comment: Update: in response to an MSDN question, I was told the toast comes from the OS and can't be disabled.